# How to reverse digits of integer?

Tags: java, reverse

```
public static int reverse(int n) {
    int result = 0;
    while (n > 0) {
        result = result * 10 + n % 10;
        n = n / 10;
    }
    return result;
}
```

I'm trying to reverse the digits of integer. Instead of doing the codes like what I have done, is there any other way to do it? Can i reverse it using java stream?

Comment: Yes, there are other ways to do it, but what's wrong with your way?

Comment: @Eran Nothing wrong. But i just want to learn a new way to write this code. I am trying to learn java stream but not sure how to do it.

Comment: Nice question. As you already have working code to reverse the integers, maybe you really want to ask what the best way is?

Comment: So how do you plan to handle trailing zeros?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OK, here's a fun implementation with `IntStream`:

```
public static int reverse (int n) {
     return IntStream.iterate (n, i -> i/10) // produces a infinite IntStream of n, n/10, 
                                             // n/100, ...
                     .limit(10) // 10 elements are sufficient, since int has <= 10 digits
                     .filter (i -> i > 0) // remove any trailing 0 elements
                     .map(i -> i % 10) // produce an IntStream of the digits in reversed 
                                       // order
                     .reduce (0, (r,i) -> r*10 + i); // reduce the reversed digits back
                                                     // to an int
}
```

For example, for the input 123456789, it will first generate the infinite `IntStream`:

```
123456789,12345678,1234567,123456,12345,1234,123,12,1,0,0,...
```

After limiting to 10 elements and removing the 0s, we are left with:

```
123456789,12345678,1234567,123456,12345,1234,123,12,1
```

After mapping each element to its last digit, we get:

```
9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,1
```

Now we just have to reduce the `IntStream` in a manner similar to what you did in your question - add each element to the intermediate result multiplied by 10:

```
((((0 * 10 + 9) * 10 + 8) * 10 + 7) * 10 ....) * 10 + 1
```

Note that if the input number has 10 digits and the last digit > 1, the reversed result will overflow.

It also doesn't support negative input.

Answer (score 9):

Another way would be

```
int digits = 12345;
StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(String.valueOf(digits));
System.out.println(buf.reverse());
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(buf.toString()));
```

Comment: Hi, does it mean that i have to convert the integer to String? So the output of this code would be String data type of integer?

Comment: Thi code converts the int to a String and then reverses the String. If you want to have the result as an int you could then just use `Integer.parseInt(buf.reverse().toString())` to convert the String back to an int

Answer (score 0):

A `Stream` solution which returns for a given number the reversed `String`:

```
int n = 10101010;
String reveresed = String.valueOf(n)
        .chars()
        .mapToObj(Character::getNumericValue)
        .reduce("", (l, r) -> r + l, (l, r) -> l + r);
System.out.println(reveresed); // 01010101
```

If we convert the reversed `String` to an `Integer` and print it we will lose the leading zero:

```
System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(reveresed).toString()); // 1010101
```

Answer (score 0):

One more stream and Math fun implementation.

```
public static long reverse(int n) {
    return Stream.iterate(
            Map.entry(0, n % 10),
            entry -> Math.pow(10, entry.getKey()) <= n,
            entry -> Map.entry(entry.getKey() + 1,
                    (int) (n % (int) Math.pow(10, entry.getKey() + 2) / Math.pow(10, entry.getKey() + 1))))
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .map(Integer::longValue)
            .reduce(0L, (r, i) -> r * 10 + i);
}
```

You should return long in your method, anyway. But StringBuilder is the best here.

Answer (score 0):

Along with the other answers, you can try this implementation as well.

```
public class MyStreamReverser {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        streamApiReverser(-9008);

        // other outputs to test:
        // streamApiReverser(20000090);
        // streamApiReverser(-04);
        // streamApiReverser(39-02);
    }

    private static void streamApiReverser(int n) {
        // produce an array of strings each having one digit
        String[] stringArray = String.valueOf(n).split("\\B");
        Stream<String> stringStream = Arrays.stream(stringArray);
        stringStream.collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new))
                .descendingIterator()
                .forEachRemaining(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
8
0
0
-9
```

Note - Does not play well with leading zeros. `09` doesn't work (since those are treated as octals), works with trailing zeros, should be fine with negatives (but further testing needed).

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to reverse an integer is to parse it into a string, reverse it, and parse it back into a integer.

```
public static int reverse(int num) {
    StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer(String.valueOf(num););
    stringBuffer.reverse();
    return Integer.parseInt(stringBuffer.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the quickest answer will be :

```
  public int reverse(int x) {
    int rev = 0;
    while (x != 0) {
        int pop = x%10;
        x /= 10;
        if (rev > Integer.MAX_VALUE/10 || (rev == Integer.MAX_VALUE / 10 && pop > 7)) return 0;
        if (rev < Integer.MIN_VALUE/10 || (rev == Integer.MIN_VALUE / 10 && pop < -8)) return 0;
        rev = rev*10+pop;
    }
    return rev;
}
```